# synonyms about service: service, web-services, map-service, amazon-web-services?

Tags: discussion, tags

the [tags page](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tags) shows these when filtered for `service`

[service](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/service) × 2
[web-services](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-services) × 34
[mapservice](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mapservice) × 9
[amazon-web-services](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amazon-web-services) x 1

*Amazon* could be deleted as it's used only once, and found easily in a search.

the 2 *Service* questions are both map server questions.

*Web-services*, the largest category overall, has a lot of map servers or services questions (4 of first 10 for example), so is [mapservice](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mapservice) meaningfully different? I think `mapservice` should be merged with `web-service`. The [wms](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wms) (x 49) and [wfs](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wfs) (x34) are available if they truly need to be distinguished.

Comment: 'service' merged with 'web-services' - mapservices can be local or WAN. amazon-web-services might be more popular in the future (?)

Comment: @Mapperz websites can be local or WAN as well. In general usage people say "web page" when they mean "view with browser".

Answer (score 1):

Sorry about the late reply, Matt.  I see that [web-services](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-services) has a clear wiki entry that makes it appear more general than [mapservice](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mapservice).  Do you still think they should be merged?  In the meantime, [service](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/service) appears to have been merged with [web-services] and [amazon-web-services](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amazon-web-services) looks like it disappeared.

Comment: I would still consider merging them. Mapservice has only grown by 3 questions in the intervening 6 months (so maybe a delayed response is not so bad! It provided room to grow stats) while web-services has grown by 13. I do note that the mapservices Q's are more tightly focussed on, well, map services. So we could embark on a re-tagging effort to move map service Q's in web-services over. That might mean people don't find them as easily, since they're clearly choosing `web` over `map`.